# Validate page numbers/ranges for printing

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a regular expression for matching a particular pattern which is as follows.

We all are familiar with the pattern that we give while printing selective pages via a word document. i.e.

- We can use comma and hyphen
- no other special characters allowed
- should start and end with a number
- Comma and hyphen not allowed together, etc

**Valid values:**

```
1, 3, 6-9
1-5, 5
6, 9
```

**Invalid values:**

```
,5
5-,9
9-5,
2,6-
```

I have been using the pattern `(([0-9]+)|(\\d.*[-,]\\d.*)+)` but it does not work for all permutation combination.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use this regex in Java:

```
^\d+(?:-\d+)?(?:,\h*\d+(?:-\d+)?)*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lS8vP9/37)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `\d+(?:-\d+)?`: Match 1+ digits *optionally* followed by hyphen and 1+ digits
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `,`: Match a comma
  - `\h*`: Match 0 or more whitespaces
  - `\d+(?:-\d+)?`: Match 1+ digits *optionally* followed by hyphen and 1+ digits
- `)*`: End non-capture group. `*` repeats this group 0 or more times
- `$`: End

Answer (score 5):

The following regex will validate that it is a comma-separated list of either positive natural number or range of number (which consist of 2 positive natural numbers separated by `-`):

```
^\d+(-\d+)?(?:,\d+(?:-\d+)?)*+$
```

In string literal:

```
"^\\d+(-\\d+)?(?:,\\d+(?:-\\d+)?)*+$"
```

If you are wondering about the `*+`, it is the *possessive* version of the usual 0-or-more quantifier `*`. Basically, it reduces backtracking. This syntax is available in Java and PCRE, but for languages without support, drop the `+` in `*+`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a class from my library that takes an argument like "1,2,3-6,4-5" and outputs a list of distinct integers [1,2,3,4,5,6].

```java
package se.imagick.scrap;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class RangeParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ranges = "1,2,3-6,4-5";
        List<Integer> rangeList = getDistinctNumbers(ranges);
        System.out.println(rangeList);
    }

    public static List<Integer> getDistinctNumbers(String ranges) {

        return Arrays.stream(ranges.split(","))
                .map(s -> s.replace(" ", ""))
                .map(Range::new)
                .flatMap(range -> range.render().stream())
                .distinct()
                .sorted()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static class Range {
        private int start;
        private int stop;

        public Range(String rangeStr) {
            String[] rangeArray = rangeStr.split("-");
            int length = rangeArray.length;

            if (length < 1 || length > 2) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong number of arguments in a Range: " + length);
            }

            start = Integer.parseInt(rangeArray[0]);
            stop = (length == 1) ? start : Integer.parseInt(rangeArray[1]);

            if (stop < start) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Stop before start!");
            }
        }

        public List<Integer> render() {
            List<Integer> pageList = new ArrayList<>(stop - start + 1);
            for (Integer i = start; i < stop + 1; i++) {
                pageList.add(i);
            }

            return pageList;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to avoid ***char*** imput erros, just place before "List":

```
ranges = ranges.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z.]", "");
List<Integer>...
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow!
my first Regex!

I think this allow spaces before digits...

^\s?\d+(-\d+)?(?:,\s?\d+(?:-\d+)?)*$

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

This solution allowed only range starting at 1 not 0.

Test it here
https://regex101.com/r/3dDGLv/1

```
^[1-9][0-9]*(?:-\d+)?(?:,\h*[1-9][0-9]*(?:-\d+)?)*$
```

For PHP or javascript use :

```
/^[1-9][0-9]*(?:-\d+)?(?:,\s*[1-9][0-9]*(?:-\d+)?)*$/
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a class that combines multiple answers into an overall solution. Use it like:

```java
final var range = RangeValidator.normalize( "-5, 7-11, 13, 15-20, 30-"  );
final var validator = new RangeValidator( range );

if( validator.test( 9 ) && validator.test( 42 ) ) {
  System.out.println( "9 and 42 are in range" );
}

final var empty = new RangeValidator( "" );

if( empty.test( 101 ) ) {
  System.out.println( "all numbers are valid" );
}
```

Note that the specification differs slightly from the question in that the upper-bound can be left unbounded (accepts up to max integer), which may be desirable when printing pages.

```java
/**
 * Responsible for answering whether a given integer value falls within a
 * set of range specifiers. For example, if the range is "1-3, 5, 7-9, 11-",
 * then values of 0, 4, and 10 return {@code false} while values of 2, 5,
 * and 37 would return {@code true}.
 */
public final class RangeValidator implements Predicate<Integer> {

  /**
   * Container for a pair of integer values that can answer whether a given
   * value is included within the bounds provided by the pair.
   */
  private static class Range {
    private final int mLo;
    private final int mHi;

    private Range( final int lo, final int hi ) {
      assert lo <= hi;

      mLo = lo;
      mHi = hi;
    }

    private boolean includes( final int i ) {
      return mLo <= i && i <= mHi || mLo == -1 && mHi == -1;
    }
  }

  private final List<Range> mRanges = new ArrayList<>();

  /**
   * Creates an instance of {@link RangeValidator} that can verify whether
   * an integer value will fall within one of the numeric ranges in the
   * given listing.
   *
   * @param range The listing of ranges to validate against.
   */
  public RangeValidator( final String range ) {
    assert normalize( range ).equals( range );

    parse( range );
  }

  @Override
  public boolean test( final Integer integer ) {
    for( final var range : mRanges ) {
      if( range.includes( integer ) ) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }

  /**
   * Given a string meant to represent a comma-separated range of numbers,
   * this will ensure that the range meets the formatting requirements.
   *
   * @param range The sequences to validate (can be {@code null}).
   * @return The given range with all non-conforming characters removed, or
   * the empty string if {@code null} was provided.
   */
  public static String normalize( final String range ) {
    return range == null
      ? ""
      : range.matches( "^\\d+(-\\d+)?(?:,\\d+(?:-\\d+)?)*+$" )
      ? range
      : range.replaceAll( "[^-,\\d\\s]", "" );
  }

  /**
   * Populates the internal list of {@link Range} instances.
   *
   * @param s The string containing zero or more comma-separated integer
   *          ranges, themselves separated by hyphens.
   */
  private void parse( final String s ) {
    for( final var commaRange : normalize( s ).split( "," ) ) {
      final var hyphenRanges = commaRange.split( "-" );
      final Range range;

      if( hyphenRanges.length == 2 ) {
        final var hrlo = hyphenRanges[ 0 ].trim();
        final var hrhi = hyphenRanges[ 1 ].trim();

        if( hrlo.isEmpty() ) {
          range = new Range( 1, Integer.parseInt( hrhi ) );
        }
        else {
          final var lo = Integer.parseInt( hrlo );
          final var hi = Integer.parseInt( hrhi );

          range = new Range( lo, hi );
        }
      }
      else if( hyphenRanges.length == 1 ) {
        final var hri = hyphenRanges[ 0 ].trim();

        if( hri.isEmpty() ) {
          range = new Range( -1, -1 );
        }
        else {
          final var i = Integer.parseInt( hyphenRanges[ 0 ].trim() );
          final var index = commaRange.trim().indexOf( '-' );

          // If the hyphen is to the left of the number, the range is bounded
          // from 0 to the number. Otherwise, the range is "unbounded" starting
          // at the number.
          if( index == -1 ) {
            range = new Range( i, i );
          }
          else if( index == 0 ) {
            range = new Range( 1, i );
          }
          else {
            range = new Range( i, Integer.MAX_VALUE );
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        // Ignore the range.
        range = new Range( 0, 0 );
      }

      mRanges.add( range );
    }
  }
}
```